# Ionic either doesn't show back button or page doesn't load at all

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a new page from an existing page with a back button. I have recreated the issue here in a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iIVwTaaTsS9q0haEzypu). In the trip analytics option When I click the first card i.e. Enter Home address. I want the todayDetail .html page to come up with a back button. I have already tried two approaches 
First approach The ng-click approach. In which I give `$state.go(statename)` to give that page. But then I wouldn't get a back button as the navigation stack is changed.
Second approach - If I keep the navigation stack i.e. keep the state name as initial.trips.today.todayDetail. The page doesn't load at all.

What is the issue? How should I go about it?

Comment: Dear @Saras, I didn't get the meaning of line 'I am trying to create a new page from an existing page with a back button'.
Can please explain more about this.
Thanks!

Comment: @SwapnilMMane the error was resolved I will post it here shortly

Comment: @SarasArya Can you please post your solution... :) . You wrote that you resolved the problem...

Comment: The issue is solved in plunker only. I am little busy. Will try and post the solution as soon as I find time..